# How to update more than one row in pl/sql

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to update a column in a table on every row from a query.  The code I have is:

```
UPDATE CUSTOM_ISR_ASSET_DETAILS SET COUNTSYSTEMASSETS = ( Select  Count(PARENT_ID) as COUNTSYSTEMASSETS 
                              from PM_ENTITY 
                              inner join
                                (SELECT 
                                pm_entity.PM_ENTITY_ID,
                                response_text.response_text
                                FROM pm_entity 
                                INNER JOIN response_text  
                                ON pm_entity.pm_entity_id=response_text.parent_id 
                                AND response_text.question_id = '000ZLIJCA0003MI82Z000UWLUTG000000P4V') TBL_StandardRollup
                              on PM_ENTITY.PM_ENTITY_ID = TBL_StandardRollup.PM_ENTITY_ID
                              WHERE (TBL_StandardRollup.response_text = 'Standard')
                              group by PARENT_ID);
```

What I'm trying to do is update each row with a count for each parent id but, obviously, this returns > 1 row so the update fails.  So, I can't do this with this sql code.

How can I do this so that each row is updated with a count of parent ids?

Comment: You are asking us to guess your requirement from code that DOESN'T meet it. It can't work that way. What are the tables (table names, column names and data types) involved in the problem, and what are you trying to update? Please put that in plain English, not in code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement. This would be something like:

```
merge into CUSTOM_ISR_ASSET_DETAILS c
using (/*YOUR SUB_QUERY*/) d
on (d.response_text = c./*what column 'standard' come from*/)
when matched then update set COUNTSYSTEMASSETS = d.COUNTSYSTEMASSETS;
```

I'm not able to define what is join condition. I guess on column where value `'standard'` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You have `SELECT COUNT(x) GROUP BY x` I think what you need is to correlate that query and have it only return one row:

```
UPDATE CUSTOM_ISR_ASSET_DETAILS
SET COUNTSYSTEMASSETS = (
    SELECT  Count(PARENT_ID)
    FROM whatever
    WHERE whatever.PARENT_ID = CUSTOM_ISR_ASSET_DETAILS.PARENT_ID ) ;
```

That way the subquery is returning only a single row corresponding to the row you are updating.

Comment: Yes that would work for one row.  The problem is I need to update each row with a total value grouped by the parent on each row of CUSTOM_ISR_ASSET_DETAILS table.

Comment: That statement is going to update all rows, correlating the right hand side is the key.